# Google Closure Compiler Service is giving invalid code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-closure-compiler, velocity.js

I am using Closure Compiler at https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/ to obfuscate/minfy my JS code, but there goes something wrong. I set up a page with a script to recreate the problem.

My HTML5 code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.min.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>text</p>    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My JS code:

```
$("p").text("val changed");
$("p").velocity({left: 60},{duration: 2000});
```

That code is working, no errors.
Then I want to minify/obfuscate it, so I go to https://closure-compiler.appspot.com

I include the url's of jQuery and Velocity.js and set the optimization to advanced.

Code:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @code_url http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js
// @code_url http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.min.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

$("p").text("val changed");
$("p").velocity({left: 60},{duration: 2000});
```

Then I wait a few seconds till it is compiled, then a long block of code is generated and I copy it into script.min.js. After that I change my HTML document slightly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>text</p>    
    <script src="script.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then I open the my HTML page and I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

But... I included the jQuery and Velocity.js libraries and they are also compiled. What have I done wrong?

Please help my, it's important.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the output contain jQuery? Note that those libraries may not work properly with advanced compilation because the probably haven't been designed for it. Dos it work if you switch to another mode?

Comment: Yes, the output contains jQuery. And it works if I switch to another mode, but then the Closure Compiler isn't useful for my anymore as it doesn't change variable names and so on.

Comment: Well, if you read the documentation about advanced compilation mode, you will see that code has to be written in a certain way in order to make sure that some things are not renamed or removed. jQuery is likely not written that way. SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATION renames variables though: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/compilation_levels#simple_optimizations

Comment: Should the full(not minified/obfuscated) version of jQuery work with Closure Compiler?

Comment: For `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`, make that definitely not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you read [Which Compilation Level is Right For Me?](http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2012/09/which-compilation-level-is-right-for-me.html)

In short, `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` can only be used with libraries that support it. The jQuery source does not (you have to use it with externs).

You should be using `SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS` level which is roughly equivalent to other compressing compilers like UglifyJS and is safe for most code.

`SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS` will rename variables that are not in the global scope. If you wrap your code in an anonymous function, you'll see this behavior.

Comment: Yes - as long as YOUR code is compatible with `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`. Here's the jQuery externs: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/contrib/externs/jquery-1.9.js